# Bash script for beeping the number of minutes

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write that If no chime if the time lies between 0 minute and 20 minutes past the hour, one chime if the time lies between 20 minutes and 40 minutes past the hour, and two chimes if the time lies between 40 minutes and 60 minutes past the hour, between the two chimes, sleep 1 second.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%M)
count=0
sleep 1s # sleep for one second
let count=count+1
minute=$(date +%M)
if [[ $minute -gt 20 && $minute -le 39 ]]; then
echo -e "\a"
elif [[ $minute -gt 40 && $minute -le 59 ]]; then
echo -e "\a\a" && sleep 1s
else
    echo  -ne "\a"
fi
```

20s-40s is worked, but others not, and how can I write the sleep between the beeping.

Actually, I have asked once but its my first time so I don't know the rules here I apologise for that and Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I've voted to reopen your existing question but please be responsive to comments and provide details requested, and don't create an identical question simply because your existing one has been closed.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience to you jesse, I just learn how to use this form. . . I thought that question is closed so I ask again

Comment: Keep in mind that negatively-scored questions could affect your ability to ask future questions; I believe that **deleted** negatively-score questions count doubly in that calculation, so it pays to be careful with your questions and to repair the ones that you can. Something to consider going forward! See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998 for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Compare the current time in minutes past the hour to the ranges in which to do one or two chimes, as you have attempted to do, or
2. Notice that the given time intervals are in even bits, with 20 minutes in each interval, and simply calculate the number of chimes to produce.

The way I see it, you have slightly *too much* code in your script.  Let's start by removing everything that is not used or that will not be used at the end:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

minute=$(date +%M)  # or, in bash 4.2+: printf -v minute '%(%M)T' -1

if [[ $minute -gt 20 && $minute -le 39 ]]; then
    echo -e "\a"
elif [[ $minute -gt 40 && $minute -le 59 ]]; then
    echo -e "\a\a" && sleep 1s
else
    echo  -ne "\a"
fi
```

Then let's look at the logic that you are using:

- If the current number of minutes past the hour is greater than 20 and less or equal to 39, then you chime once.  This seems ok to me.
- If the current number of minutes past the hour is greater than 40 and less or equal to 59, you chime twice and then sleep for one second.  This seems like a problem as the pause should probably come *between* the two chimes.  You can solve this easily by

  ```
  echo -e '\a'
  sleep 1
  echo -e '\a'
  ```

  Also note that there is a gap in your hour.  What should happen at 40 minutes past the hour?
- Otherwise, hmm... Otherwise? The `else` branch should not be needed here.

We can simplify this logic a bit and recognize that if the time is more than 20 minutes past the hours, there should be at least on chime.

```
if [ "$minute" -gt 20 ]; then
        echo chime
fi
```

If the time is more than 40 minutes past the hour, we need to add another chime, after a pause:

```
if [ "$minute" -gt 40 ]; then
        sleep 1
        echo chime
fi
```

With this logic, you don't have to check the end of the ranges.

There is also an issue with `09`.   The `%M` format formats the number of minutes past the hour as a zero-filled two-digit number.   When a number is starting with `0` and the shell is using it in an arithmetic context, it would interpret it as an *octal* number.  This is ok for the numbers in the range `00` to `08`, but `09` is an invalid octal number.

You can fix that by removing the initial zero from `$minute`, if there is one:

```
minute=${minute#0}
```

You should do this before you try to use that value, obviously.

---

The other way to solve this is to calculate the number of chimes to produce, and just chime that many times:

```
for (( i = 0; i < (minute-1)/20; ++i )); do
        [ "$i" -ne 0 ] && sleep 1
        echo chime
done
```

This avoids sleeping before the initial chime, but otherwise adds a pause between chimes.  This would *not* work unless the the time-frames are distributed equally across the hour.

Comment: thanks a lot, that really makes sense thanks!